# Using usbnet_suspend and usbnet_resume instead of smsc95xx_suspend and smsc95xx_resume

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

We are using smsc95630 chip in our project.So during Suspand/Resume, shall i call **usbnet_suspend** and **usbnet_resume**?Is it correct? Or should i call **smsc95xx_suspend** and **smsc95xx_resume**?

Comment: There is a driver in upstream and it does it already. So, why this question?!

Comment: The SMSC chip has lot of suspend modes(suspend0,suspend1,suspend2,suspend3). But i want to suspend the whole driver(usbnet). So i would like to use it instead of smsc95xx_suspend and smsc95xx_resume.

Comment: Driver is so abstract, you can't suspend it.